# Advanced Pricing Tab for Configurable - Magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to have The Advanced Pricing Tab for Configurable products in magento 2

alternatively is there anyway i can put discounts on products

Please help!

Comment: alternatively you can apply discounts using shopping cart price rules.

Answer (score 0):

The Advanced Pricing tab is not available for a configurable product.
In M2 configurable product use prices form simple variants. So, if you need same specific price/discount for all child product, please use catalog price rules.

Comment: What are catalog price rules and where can I find them to use them @KAndy?